# "Qui y a été associé" ou "qui lui a été associé" ?

Tags: pronoms

La phrase exacte est :

> La colonne *"Remarque"* retranscrit, dans le cas d’une observation, le texte qui **y** a été associé.

J'ai naturellement écrit *y* mais j'ai un doute avec *lui*, les deux sont peut-être corrects ?

Answer (score 1):

Tout dépend de ce que l'on veut dire :

- ...qui lui a été associé

  fait référence à l'observation. À quoi est associé le texte ? Le texte est associé à l’observation, il lui est associé.
- ...qui y a été associé

  fait référence à l'endroit où le texte est placé. Où a été associé le texte ? le texte a été associé à l'observation dans la colonne "Remarque", il y est associé.

Je recommanderais la première forme.

Comment: C'est bien de l'observation qu'il s'agit dans mon cas, c'est donc *lui*. Merci. Je me demande même comment j'ai pu hésiter.